# London pre 1965 metropolitan boroughs

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I am looking for polygons of the London Metropolitan Boroughs before 1965 as kml or kmz (I am working with google maps) or shapefiles.

Comment: Statutory definition or Statistical definition ? https://en.wiki2.org/wiki/Inner_London

Comment: statutory definition

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find them at [visionofbritain.org.uk](http://visionofbritain.org.uk/maps/?layer=europe&xMin=3310675.77767&yMin=2778852.71194&xMax=3340675.77767&yMax=2808852.71194) certainly if you contact them they will have those boundaries in their DB. I'm pretty sure they are publicly archived somewhere as a condition of the grant.